# How do you install or turn on CKEditor 5 paste from word plugin

Tags: wysiwyg, installation, plugins

According to a conversation with CKEditor this feature is included in the Drupal 10 version.  They do not support it and point you to
[Documentation for paste from Word](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/pasting/paste-from-office.html)

We cannot find where to turn this on so we get a clean paste nor are there instructions for installing the plugin to Drupal 10.

Can anyone assist in how to accomplish this task.  Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a "clean paste"?  The linked feature is to keep the Office formatting, not remove it.

Comment: Yes we want the formatting for html the same way as demonstrated on the CKEditor site.  What we get is a ton of Word formatting junk when you look at source.  So the paste-from-office filter in Drupal 10.1 is not functioning.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor 5 > paste from word plugin (maintaining html formatting) inbuilt in Drupal 10 core by default : there is n**o need to any additional configuration**

While **pasting the code in text editor field** make sure select **"full html" format** otherwise the html tags 'll be stripped & it gives illusion "paste from word plugin (along with maintaining html formatting)" functionality not working in Drupal 10.

Note: check off "Limit HTML" to remove the unnecessary Word formatting

[image]

Comment: I used Full HTML yet, all the Word junk was brought over and not filtered as demonstrated on the CKEditor site.

Comment: <p class="text-align-center MsoNormal" style="line-height:normal;margin-bottom:0in;">
    <span style="color:black;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif;font-size:11.0pt;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;mso-font-kerning:0pt;mso-ligatures:none;"><strong>AGENDA</strong></span><span style="color:black;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;mso-font-kerning:0pt;mso-ligatures:none;"><o:p></o:p></span>
</p>
<p class="text-align-center MsoNormal" style="line-height:normal;margin-bottom:0in;">

Comment: I see I needed to check off "Limit HTML" for it to remove the Word formatting.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah this setting  off at my end which leads to remove these unnecessary Word formatting